# how to setup .htaccess: redirect/ /%postname% to /%category%/%postname%

Tags: redirect

how to setup .htaccess: redirect/ /%postname% to /%category%/%postname%

My current permalink structure is: %postname%

I'd like it to be: /%category%/%postname%

Comment: You shouldn't use HTAccess for changes like this, but, WP will do this automatically,  it'll redirect to the canonical URL. So if you change your permalinks you've changed the canonical URL and it'll redirect to the new location. All you need to do is change your permalinks

Comment: I have a lot of posts and when people click on a link they get an error 404.

Comment: To be honest, I would just throw in the Redirection plugin by John Godley and update the permalink structure. Or, if you have already changed them, set some rules in the plugin to handle your redirects.